# Wordpress: Resize $term attachment using url

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing, attachment, image-size

I've submitted this question into Wordpress Section without success for the moment. The question can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232340/resize-term-attachment-using-url).

I'm using this plugin for attaching an image to a custom taxonomy. The plugin's function returns the attached term's image as following:

```
function get_wp_term_image($term_id){
    return get_option('_category_image'.$term_id);  
}
```

**EDIT**: `get_wp_term_image($term_id)` returns the image's url.

It works fine but I'd like to resize the returned image because I'm using it in a page displaying all taxonomy categories with relative thumbs. It means that if you upload a big image you get that and the page becomes very heavy to load. I've tried to add this hook without success, in my page loop:

```
$term_id = $term->term_id;
if (function_exists('get_wp_term_image'))
   {
    $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term_id);
    //tried this
    $term_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($term_id, 'smalltax');
    //and this
    $image_id = attachment_url_to_postid($meta_image);
    //no success
    }
```

- In the first case I've assumed that `wp_get_attachment_image_src` hook considers the attachment from whatever id but I was wrong. **NB.** I don't have the image ID, I have the `image url` and the `term_id`
- In the second case I've thought to get the $image_id with the
  `attachment_url_to_postid` hook and then resize with some other
  tweaking.

Can you provide a solution? Even helping to modify the plugin itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$term_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta_image, 'smalltax');
```

I assume that $meta_image is the ID of the image you are looking for... if so, my line will work.  You are passing the $term_id to that function, which is the ID of a term, not the ID of an image.

**UPDATE**

Since you've specified that the $meta_image is the URL to the full sized image, then in order to get what you want it to get it's ID first... then call a default WP function to retrieve the image size you want.  Kind of a hack about way, but it appears to be your only option... So you'll need a function similar to this:

```
// Function to get an image's ID by it's full sized URL
function get_image_id_by_url( $image_url ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ) ); 
    return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

Then you'll use something on these lines:

```
$image_id = get_image_id_by_url( $image_url );
$$term_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'smalltax' );
```

Comment: Yes I've tried it! Actually $meta_image is the url of image. For that reason I'm trying something or to get the id from the url, or transform the function to return the ID! I will edit the answer to make it clearer!

Comment: It would, of course, be better if you stored the ID of the image, and not the URL.

Comment: Thank you man! That's a great solution. Eventually how could assign an image id when I upload it? I have this function to save the image: `function categoryimagesave($term_id){
    if(isset($_POST['tag-image'])){
        if(isset($_POST['tag-image']))
            update_option('_category_image'.$term_id,$_POST['tag-image'] );
    }
}`

Comment: This function won't need to change.  What needs to change is how you are getting `$_POST['tag-image']`.  That's where the magic would happen.  Show me that function and I can help.

Comment: here is a paste bin of php file handling the upload http://pastebin.com/HQmMdSyG (php). This file is interacting with this js http://pastebin.com/QzESu6nf Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, old code... The first pastebin link, line 61. They are pulling the src attribute from the url string. I don't know what's in the jQuery(html) element, but I would be a lot of money the ID is in there... Console.log it and see... Then parse out the ID instead of the src.

Comment: Beware you are editing a plugin, so changes will be lost on upgrading. Make a note of your changes to do it again if needs be.